# Permission Denied while running vb script

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I have written a vb script to open a file with different filetype other than the original filetype(eg : from .doc filetype to .txt filetype)

below is my code

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("notepad" & "C:\OpenWith_Shell32_Doc.doc")
```

the above code was working fine but one day i edited the 'notepad' to 'wordpad' it is giving the below error..but i undo the changes then also it is giving the same error...

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'
>   Permission denied

Comment: can you tell us what OS you're running?

Comment: Duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200932/permission-denied-while-running-vb-script

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Duplicate of itself? :)

Comment: @Helen, oops, pasted in the wrong dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192093/error-while-converting-xml-to-qctester-file-type

Answer (score 0):

missing space between "notepad" and "C:\OpenWith_Shell32_Doc.doc" should work with notepad and wordpad (if you put a space in)